# How to return lowest value tuple of list of tuples?

Tags: haskell

I have a list of tuples with a name and a float. How can I return the tuple with the lowest float value?

Example

```
[("bob",23),("Alice",32),("Susan",1)]

rtnLowestDist :: [(Name, Float)] -> (Name, Float)
```

returns `("Susan",1)`

Comment: I tried it earlier but it didn't work because I didn't know I had to import Data.List or Data.Ord

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `minimumBy` from `Data.List` to find the minimum element, and apply `comparing snd` to compare tuples by their second component.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

rtnLowestDist = minimumBy (comparing snd)
```